# How does parameter by name works on this example in C++?

Tags: parameters, scope, static

I know that passing by name substitutes the formal parameter by the real one, but I dind't get it when the code is using static scope.

For the following code, it will print:

> x = 1 y = 2
>
> **x = 6   y = 6**
>
> x = 5   y = 4
>
> **x = 12  y = 12**
>
> x = 5   y = 4
>   x = 1   y = 2

I don't understand the second e fourth line.

```
int x = 3, y = 4;

void f(int y) {

   y = y + x;
   cout << x << ' ' << y;
}

void g() {

   int x = 5;
   cout << x << ' ' << y;
   f(x);
   cout << x << ' ' << y;
}

int main() {

  int x = 1;
  int y = 2;
  cout << x << ' ' << y;
  f(x);
  g();
  cout << x << ' '<< y;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all, that is C++, not C. Second, no, it won't print that: https://ideone.com/prPHGi

Comment: Thanks Dark, I wrote it wrong(edited). And yes, it will print that using static scope and passing parameter by name - my teacher made it at class. You compiled it without considering that the parameters should be passes by name, right!?

Comment: I compiled it in the only way it can be compiled, as standard C++. There is no such thing as "pass by name" or something like that that can be turned on in compilation.

Comment: Actually there is a way to change how the code is going do deal with the functions ... read that http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~lou/314-f04-slides/topic10_params.pdf

Comment: If you want an answer about C++, don't show me your professor's slides (which, by the way, are talking in generalizations about many programming languages). Show me where in the C++ standard, or an example in a particular compiler. The way C++ passes parameters is specified by the language specification and cannot be changed without making the compiler non-conformant to the standard.